# integrate a tkinter interface in a web page

Tags: python, html, tkinter

Is there a way to integrate a `tkinter interface` into a `HTML` web page?

Comment: Take a look on [`CloudTk`](http://cloudtk.tcl-lang.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to embed a Tkinter GUI directly into an HTML page. But, you can use a tool like [PyWebView](https://pywebview.flowrl.com/guide/usage.html) to wrap a Tkinter GUI in a webview, which is a component that displays web pages inside a desktop application. This gives you the ability to display the Tkinter GUI in a webview within a web page, but the GUI itself would still be running as a desktop application.

Comment: It's possible, it's just not easy.

Comment: Thats what I tried to explain in the second part of my annswer ^^"

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but it requires a tremendous amount of work. For example, replit.com makes it possible to run tkinter in the browser. However, it requires a lot of back-end engineering with a deep understanding of how tkinter draws windows, and may have many server-side requirements that a typical web server won't have.

I'm guessing somebody spent 100's of hours to make that work.

[image: screenshot of tkinter running in replit.com]

Answer (score 0):

I think **py-code** might work but I'm not sure. Open an html file and try it there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are better methods with which you can create web apps.

If you have web-server(Either shared / dedicated),

1. Install python in your server
2. Install Flask. (It won't take much time to learn flask)
3. A module called Brython is available. With which you can write javascript logics in python itself. This can be installed from: brython.info
4. Jinja template engine

With the above tools and modules, you can create html page to deliver your app.